# How to deactivate a QVideoProbe?

Tags: python, video, pyqt5, pyside2, qtmultimedia

According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtMultimedia/QVideoProbe.html#PySide2.QtMultimedia.PySide2.QtMultimedia.QVideoProbe.setSource) "If source is zero, this probe will be deactivated"

But calling setSource(0) gives the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'PySide2.QtMultimedia.QVideoProbe.setSource' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtMultimedia.QVideoProbe.setSource(int)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtMultimedia.QVideoProbe.setSource(PySide2.QtMultimedia.QMediaObject)
  PySide2.QtMultimedia.QVideoProbe.setSource(PySide2.QtMultimedia.QMediaRecorder)
```

Im running my code on raspberry pi 4 with Rpi Os Bullseye 64bit and PySide2 version 5.15.2.

Example code:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PySide2.QtMultimedia import *
from PySide2.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.available_cameras = QCameraInfo.availableCameras()
        self.camera = QCamera(self.available_cameras[0])
        self.probe = QtMultimedia.QVideoProbe(self)
        self.probe.videoFrameProbed.connect(self.processFrame)
        self.probe.setSource(self.camera)
        self.probe.setSource(0)
        
    def processFrame(self, frame):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source object can be cleared like this:

```
self.probe.setSource(None)
```

In C++, passing zero to a pointer argument means the function will recieve a null pointer. Since this can't be done explicitly in Python, PySide/PyQt allow `None` to be passed instead.

Generally speaking, it's always advisable to consult the [Qt Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoprobe.html#setSource) in cases like this. The PySide/PyQt docs are a work in progress and are mostly auto-generated from the Qt Docs. This can often result in somewhat garbled or misleading descriptions that don't accurately reflect how the given API works in practice.